What Are the Implications of Removing SYSTEM Account Permissions on Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) snap in?
We are currently using Windows Server 2012 in our domain controller environment. On our domain controller, we have denied other user accounts from having  full privileges in ADUC snap in to limit their access to view or change Active directory users and computer objects .
We have some doubt on whether "SYSTEM" account can also be removed from access , since we want to limit the modify privileges to only certain accounts. According to Microsoft’s documentation, it is generally advised not to remove permissions from the SYSTEM account. The document mentions that removing SYSTEM account permissions is not recommended, as it is required for many services and processes in the Windows operating system that need the capability to sign in internally, such as during a Windows installation. But this is applicable for the computer, and there is no mention of Active Directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts#system
But, I do not see the necessity of "SYSTEM" account having full privilege on ADUC. Also there is not much information available for the same. Here’s what we want to understand:
1. What are the potential consequences of removing SYSTEM account permissions on ADUC?
2. Are there specific risks or issues that might arise from making changes to SYSTEM account permissions in a Active Directory environment?
If no, then what are the recommended permissions which can be given to "SYSTEM" Account in Active Directory ?  We are seeking insights or experiences related to these concerns. Any guidance or advice on this matter would be highly appreciated.

Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

AD already has a mechanism for limiting what users can view. You need to stick to the vendor procedures and recommendations. This includes not modifying system permission, there is no need to do that. https://serverfault.com/questions/496901/limiting-view-of-active-directory-users-and-computers

This seems a bit like tilting at windmills.

If you're at the point of "I need to remove SYSTEM access from AD", then you've missed the part of the process like 7 steps ago where you should not have been giving SYSTEM access to a user.  If somebody has SYSTEM on a DC, the ballgame is long over -- regardless of whatever ACL you throw in AD.
